# ORM / ORM-like lib in Go

Tags: mysql, orm, go

I'm working with a legacy Mysql DB with a lot of tables, and about to expose it as an REST api server under some privilege control using ACL. The server would be using Go for better concurrency support.

So is there a Go ORM library that supports inspecting legacy MySQLDB and generating model code that I can start with?

Or is there any other method to achieve same goal?

Comment: There is a fairly recent blog post about Go ORMs [here](http://jmoiron.net/blog/golang-orms) . Not sure if any of those fit your needs.

Comment: @ANisus that's a dead link. Use [this link](http://jmoiron.net/blog/golang-orms/).

Comment: @nemo My mistake. Removed the trailing /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/asdf072/struct-create 
This can generate struct code from MySQLDB

Answer (score 8):

The following list exists today:

- https://github.com/gosexy/db
- https://github.com/eaigner/jet
- https://github.com/eaigner/hood
- https://github.com/coocood/qbs (forked from hood)
- https://github.com/astaxie/beedb
- https://github.com/coopernurse/gorp
- https://github.com/jmoiron/modl (fork of gorp)
- https://github.com/go-xorm/xorm

For your particular case: hood allows automatic schema generation

Comment: Thanks for the info but Hood seems not support "inspectdb" into model definition files. Sorry maybe I'm using wrong word for "inspectdb".

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm

A really cool ORM aims to be developer friendly written by me ;)

Comment: i like this one.. much like Ruby's DataMapper